# How does Metal Shader Language's (MSL) atomic_uint bridge to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, atomic, metal

In my Swift iOS Metal App, I would like to have a Metal Shading Language (MSL) kernel like so:

```
kernel void someKernel(device atomic_uint &counter [[buffer(0)]], ...)
{
    ...
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How does MSL's atomic_uint bridge to Swift?
2. What is the size of atomic_uint in memory so that I can decide how many bytes to reserve for the MTLBuffer on the Swift/App side?

Thank your for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your initial question:

1. `atomic_uint` maps to a `UInt32` type in Swift.
2. It's going to be 4 bytes or `MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride` to allocate.

And to add: atomics aren't going to be atomic between CPU and GPU. Meaning, you can't change memory atomically on CPU and see this change atomically on GPU and vice versa. So in the end, this is why it maps to just a `UInt32`. To guarantee that CPU sees GPU changes you will need to wait for a buffer to complete by either adding a completion handler or by signaling `MTLSharedEvent` on a GPU timeline and making a listener for that event in CPU code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I did not assume that there is atomicity between CPU and GPU, but you pointing it out so clearly set off the light bulb that there is no need to have anything else than UInt32 on the CPU/Swift side, and we do not actually need any atomic counterpart there.  I want to just allocate the space with CPU, then let the GPU do its thing (write atomically into that memory space), and then when that is done, read out the resulting value with the CPU.  Thank you again for help!

Comment: I would also advice to measure a lot if you are going to use `device`-atomics in Metal. Basically, if you have a wide dispatch and every lane touches an atomic in `device` memory, there's probably a case for `threadgroup` atomics + one access to device per simd-group. Otherwise you are gonna hit a very hard limit on a performance.

Comment: Yes, that I will do, thank you so much!